# Complex Dataframe Merge Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes and can't quite get what I'm looking for.

Dataframe 1 looks like this.

```
Index       Date      Data1   Data2

  A    2007-07-21      76      32
  A    2007-08-13      nan     23
  B    2007-06-15      53      nan
  B    2007-07-15      87      39
```

Dataframe 2 looks like this:

```
Index       Date      Data3   Data4

  A    2007-07-24      14      nan
  A    2007-08-13      67      51
  B    2007-06-21      32      36
  B    2007-07-15      nan     91
```

The same indicies are in both dataframes.  The index labels contain duplicates.  There is some overlap in the dates but each dataframe also contains unique dates.

What I'd like in my result is the following:  rows with the same Index and Date appear ONCE in the result with combined values (Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4).   If an Index/Date combination appears once in either the left dataframe or right dataframe, that combination appears along with the relevant data from respective  data frame and nans in columns from the dataframe where values don't exist.

From the above dataframes the result would look like this:

```
Index       Date      Data1   Data2  Data3  Data4

  A    2007-07-21      76      32     nan    nan
  A    2007-07-24      nan     nan    14     nan  
  A    2007-08-13      nan     23     67      51
  B    2007-06-15      53      nan    nan    nan
  B    2007-06-21      nan     nan    32      36
  B    2007-07-15      87      39     nan     91
```

This exercise has aspects of a left join but also an outer join.  Not sure how to get this using pd.merge or pd.concat.

Thank in advance for insight.

Answer (score 2):

`set_index` + `concat`

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index(['Index','Date']),df2.set_index(['Index','Date'])],1).reset_index()
Out[1145]: 
  Index        Date  Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4
0     A  2007-07-21   76.0   32.0    NaN    NaN
1     A  2007-07-24    NaN    NaN   14.0    NaN
2     A  2007-08-13    NaN   23.0   67.0   51.0
3     B  2007-06-15   53.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
4     B  2007-06-21    NaN    NaN   32.0   36.0
5     B  2007-07-15   87.0   39.0    NaN   91.0
```

Or we can use `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2,on=['Index','Date'],how='outer')
Out[1147]: 
  Index        Date  Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4
0     A  2007-07-21   76.0   32.0    NaN    NaN
1     A  2007-08-13    NaN   23.0   67.0   51.0
2     B  2007-06-15   53.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
3     B  2007-07-15   87.0   39.0    NaN   91.0
4     A  2007-07-24    NaN    NaN   14.0    NaN
5     B  2007-06-21    NaN    NaN   32.0   36.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Does an outer join generally merge elements with common index values?.  Also, in your concat example what is the default 'how'?

Comment: @Windstorm1981, the default is `how='inner'`

Comment: @MaxU:  If with concat the default is an inner join, shouldn't that take the group/date combinations you made common to both dataframes and leave out the ones unique to each dataframe (eg, take the intersection of the dataframes?)

Comment: @Windstorm1981, my answer was about `merge`, not about `concat`. `pd.concat(..., join='outer')`

Comment: oh, I was wondering about the method use in the concat example as it is not specified.

Comment: @Windstorm1981   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html, the default for `concat` is `outer`, you can set it `inner` by using `join='inner '`